# Show configuration changes at different scope

Tags: configuration, adminhtml

I'm sure at some point I came across a module that updated the configuration section of the admin panel in order to show if a setting is changed at a lower scope. The idea being that it would be easier to navigate around in the default scope and see if a setting was changed at the website level.

I can't for the life of me find this extension, does anybody have any idea what it might have been?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean AvS_ScopeHint: https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_ScopeHint

Brilliant extension btw!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the one, the name sounds familiar though so it probably is. Looks like it does exactly what I need. I'll accept later today if nobody else comes up with alternatives. Thanks.